# Persistência com herança, relacionamento um pra um e chave primária manual

Tags: java, hibernate, modelagem, modelo-relacional, annotation

Estou desenvolvendo um projeto web de patrimônios para terminar minha graduação.
Estou utilizando Java (IDE: Spring Tool Suite), Spring, Hibernate e Mysql.

Estou tendo um problema de modelagem de dados que não estou conseguindo resolver:

[image: Exemplo de modelagem]

Uma classe Equipamento deve ter como atributo um número de patrimônio.
Cpu e Modem herdam atributos da classe Equipamento.
O atributo equipamento deverá ser representado como chave primária no banco, porém, o valor dele deverá ser digitado pelo usuário.

Obs.: Estou utilizando anotações do Hibernate

Tentei utilizar anotação @OneToOne, @Id, @NaturalId.
Todas as tentativas que tentei utilizar ou não compilam (não rodam) ou permitem que um cpu e um modem sejam cadastrados com o mesmo número de patrimônio.

Logo, qual é o caminho que eu posso utilizar para resolver esse problema?

Obrigado pela atenção!

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
```

funciona para o seu caso, desde que você utilize uma tabela Única para toda a hierarquia de classes, ou seja,

```
 @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
```

e um descritor para fazer a distinção entre as classes.

```
@OneToOne
```

é para mapeamento de composições, não de herança.

Comment: Especificamente para o meu trabalho de graduação não poderei utilizar tabela ÚnicaEntão estou utilizando 3 tabelas, uma para equipamento, 1 para cpu e 1 para modem. Em relação as classes, @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED) sendo utilizada na tabela equipamento

Answer (score 0):

No método salvar de cada classe adicionei uma procura do número de patrimônio dentro do banco de dados de equipamentos.

Se o patrimônio não estivesse dentro do banco de dados o objeto seria persistido caso contrário não.

Obrigado a quem me ajudou! =)

PS.: Perdoem-me qualquer coisa, sou novato por aqui.